# требуется синоним: parsing → синтаксический-анализ

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

метка [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) является синонимом для метки [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7):

```
парсинг → синтаксический-анализ
```

а метка [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) **не** является синонимом для той же метки ([синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7)).

мне кажется, это не совсем логично, и следует назначить [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) синонимом:

```
parsing → синтаксический-анализ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлен синоним [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) → [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7)