# Отделим ли предмет труда от его объекта (т.е. парсер от парсинга)?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

[требуется синоним: parsing → синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/559/181472)

У нас также есть метка [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser):

> Парсер - это программа или подпрограмма, позволяющая проанализировать ввод (обычно текстовый документ) и вычленить содержащиеся данные.

И еще [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80):

> Парсер (от англ. parser; «parse» — анализ, разбор) или синтаксический анализатор — часть программы, преобразующей входные данные (как правило, текст) в структурированный формат. Парсер выполняет синтаксический анализ текста.

Также есть неопределенный [анализатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), который иногда используется про синтаксический анализ, а иногда как [лексический](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9)[анализатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80).

Вопрос:

**Является ли парсер (синтаксический анализатор) отдельной концепцией или он неразрывно связан с синтаксическим анализом и должен быть синонимизирован for great justice.**

Comment: А еще Parser - это (ужасный) [язык программирования](http://www.parser.ru/)... С ним-то что делать?

Answer (score 5):

[парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) - это калька с английского parsing в его широком смысле "разбор".
А не только в смысле [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7).

Более того, синтаксические анализаторы обычно работают не напрямую с исходным текстом, а с набором лексем - результатом прохода по исходному тексту лексическим анализатором. При этом под парсером обычно подразумевается связка лексического и ситаксического анализа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Картинка честно взята с википедии, из статьи [Parsing, раздела Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages).</sub>

[Проведенная автоматическая замена](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/559/) превратила [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) в аналог тегов [язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba), [программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) или [фреймворк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba) - его теперь лепят на все подряд.

Ни разу не видел фразы

> как мне провести синтаксический анализ первого поля из вот такой строки:...

Зато что-то вроде такого встречается регулярно

> как распарсить первое поле вот такой строки:...

Я более чем уверен, что [ни подсчет символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410119/), ни [парсинг инпутов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/398920/), ни [формирование get-запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/397026/), ни [множественные вопросы по десериализации XML/JSON в Java/C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7) не имеют **прямого** отношения к синтаксическому анализу.

Десериализация использует внутри синтаксический анализатор - как и 99% вещей, так или иначе связанных с программированием.

Сейчас наблюдается какой-то треш - надо разрезать строку через `;` - используем `String.Split` и ставим метку [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7). Надо найти позицию последней запятой - ну тут точно [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7)! Парсим ответ от вконтакта, упомянули JsonNet - ну тут совсем без вариантов, точно лепим тэг.

Сам факт того, что большая часть вопросов задается с [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3), который упрямым движком исправляется на [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) - это признак того, что что-то идет не так.

Предлагаю

- Не доводить до абсурда.
- Удалить синоним, заменить в вопросах синтетический тэг [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) обратно на [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) .
- Оставить [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) для вопросов, основной темой в которых является разработка синтаксических анализаторов.

Comment: Про парсинг и синтаксический анализ понятно. C парсером-то что предлагаете делать?

Comment: @NickVolynkin оставить парсер, parser сделать синонимом. или наоборот - не принципиально. есть стандартные механизмы создания синонимов, с учетом репутации и ответов. пусть люди с репутацией > 5 по метке парсер решают, нужен им синоним или нет.

Answer (score -1):

Да, это неразрывные понятия.

К центральной метке [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) нужно добавить:

- [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser)
- [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80)
- [синтаксический-анализатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)

Answer (score -1):

Нет, необходимо оставить разделение.

[синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) для вопросов о том, как пользоваться готовыми решениями для анализа.

[синтаксический-анализатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) для вопросов о том, как разрабатывать, отлаживать, тестировать анализаторы. Сделать эту метку центральной. Использовать описание из метки [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80), т.к. это лучший вариант. Синонимизировать:

- [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser)
- [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: если ставить метку "синтаксический анализ" на всем, что связанно с регексами - то стоит добавить ее и на все вопросы по C# - потому что для выполнения любого кода на C# без синтаксического анализа также не обойтись