# Метки, связанные с парсингом

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток, переименование-метки

Предыдущие обсуждения:

- [требуется синоним: parsing → синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/559/199934),
- [Убрать синоним парсинг, parsing → синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1101/199934),
- [Отделим ли предмет труда от его объекта (т.е. парсер от парсинга)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/199934)

Вроде был достигнут консенсус, что метка [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) не синонимична остальным рассматриваемым в данном посте. Однако я не увидел аргументации, отделять ли [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80) от [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3). Полагаю, что нет, поскольку даже если разделение и имеет смысл, де-факто большинство задающих вопросы скорее всего не будут вникать, где нужно ставить метку [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80), а где [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3). Допускаю, что другие участники думают иначе.

Предложения:

- Синонимизировать метки [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) и [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing),
- Синонимизировать метки [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80) и [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser),
- Метки [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) и [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) использовать для вопросов о парсинге,
- Метки [парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80) и [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser) использовать для примеров о [языке программирования Parser](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160422092529/http://www.parser.ru/), (не очень удачный) [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/315623/199934),
- Сделать основной метку [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3), как русскоязычное название,
- Сделать основной метку [parser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parser), как название, используемое на официальном сайте языка программирования, несмотря на то, что его разработчики из России.

Comment: На беду, есть ещё и [язык Parser](http://www.parser.ru/).

Comment: @D-side, я упомянул его в предложении.

Comment: Да, я как-то пропустил этот момент. Будем считать, что напоминаю о возможной проблеме :)

Comment: Да, и я бы ещё отделил «парсинг» в смысле «синтаксический разбор» от «веб-скрейпинга»[.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est)

Comment: @VladD, [здесь](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1094/199934) вроде бы уже обсуждалось.

Comment: @СашаЧерных: Да, но это было давно. Сейчас по метке [tag:парсер] встречаются в основном вопросы типа «как мне стащить цены из конкурирующего веб-магазина», так что я бы разделил.