# Не согласен с синонимизацией меток delphi и object-pascal

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

В качестве примера приведу вопрос: [Почему не работает мой прогресс бар?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763494/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80). Описывается код для Inno Setup, который использует скрипты на Object Pascal, но никаким боком не относится к Delphi (собственно, Delphi - скорее среда программирования на языке Object Pascal, нежели язык). Вставляю метку [object-pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-pascal), вылезает метка [delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi), что неправильно. Знаю ещё пару программ, более специализированных, правда, которые тоже используют Object Pascal.

Конечно, можно вообще не вставлять метку [object-pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-pascal), но мне это кажется неправильным.

Как компромиссный вариант, можно, конечно, ввести метку [pascal-script](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal-script), но это именно компромисс.

Comment: [Знайте, кого винить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4A6v.png) :)

Comment: Кстати, на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi/synonyms) сейчас висит один голос за синомизацию. Они ещё не знают, что их ждёт.

Comment: @alexolut у меня там прав не хватает проголосовать "против", может, вы? :) Или вообще собраться всем и пойти "коту морду бить" :)

Comment: Гм... предыдущий комментарий получился двусмысленным, учитывая автора слияния меток :)

Comment: Ничего двусмысленного ... просто кого-то забанят на недельку :-D

Comment: Морду бить никому не надо. Если бы метки были отдельными, люди все равно бы не ставили их так, как задумано (delphi - на вопросы по IDE, object pascal - по языку), а лепили бы как попало. Так что Кот ничего не ухудшил. А для скриптов Inno Setup можно вообще отдельную метку запилить, если на то пошло.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight людям нужна свобода. Если синонимизация не симметрична, то её не должно быть. Однако, если сейчас её разорвать, то это потребует пересмотра имеющихся вопросов по метке [tag:delphi]. Я, кстати, не помню случаев разсинонимизации меток.

Comment: @alexolut "не помню случаев разсинонимизации меток" - неудивительно, требования к голосующим за синонимы настолько высоки, по сравнению с требованиями к созданию метки, что вероятность создать неправильный синоним довольно мала.

Comment: @alexolut, зря не помнишь: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3046/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy [OMG](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40300842#40300842) :-D Но тогда не было же разделения. Иначе я ожидал бы увидеть красную метку [meta-tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: @alexolut, метки не синонимы. А красную метку я добавил. А твои три парсера объединены. Только [tag:синтаксический-анализ] откатили.

Comment: @Qwertiy какие метки - не синонимы?

Comment: @alexolut, [tag:синтаксический-анализ] и [tag:парсинг]. Тьфу.. В прошлый раз не тот комментарий поправил. Переделал.

Comment: @alexolut, уже исправил. Я случайно комментарий перепутал.

Comment: @Qwertiy понавыбирали тут на свою голову :-D

Comment: А нельзя разделить, но старое не переделывать? В конце концов, подавляющее большинство вопросов касается и того, и другого. Вот откопал на свою голову :)

Comment: К слову, документация Inno Setup не использует выражение "object pascal" применительно к своим скриптам. Они пишут "Pascal script",  "modern Delphi-like Pascal" (http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptintro.htm). Вероятно, object pascal является чьей-то торговой маркой.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov чем мотивирован откат правки, делающей метки метками?

Comment: То, что я увидел (жаль не догадался сделать скриншот) в сообщении о  правке, просто превращало сообщение в нечто, гм, пусть будет "странное". Поэтому нажал откат.

Comment: Ок. Вернул обратно в таком случае. Сделайте скриншот в следующий раз :)

Answer (score 2):

Из [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

> Delphi — императивный структурированный объектно-ориентированный язык программирования со строгой статической типизацией переменных. Основная область использования — написание прикладного программного обеспечения.
>
> Первоначально носил название Object Pascal и исторически восходит к одноимённому диалекту языка, разработанному в фирме Apple в 1986 году группой Ларри Теслера. Однако в настоящее время термин Object Pascal чаще всего употребляется в значении языка среды программирования Delphi. **Начиная с Delphi 7 в официальных документах компания Borland стала использовать название Delphi для обозначения языка Object Pascal**.

Так, что синонимизация все-таки правильна

Comment: Возможно, выскажусь грубо, но вики - не авторитет. Я всё же не программист, трогать программерские темы не буду, но то, что там порой написано по химии, биологии и физике - хоть святых выноси. Так что ссылка на вики не является компетентной . А вот фраза из официального руководства Borland - вполне. Следующим комментарием добавлю.

Comment: Object Pascal is a high-level, compiled, strongly typed language that supports 
structured and object-oriented design. Its benefits include easy-to-read code, quick 
compilation, and the use of multiple unit files for modular programming.
Object Pascal has special features that support Borland
’
s component framework and 
RAD environment. For the most part, descriptions and examples in this manual 
assume that you are using Object Pascal to develop applications using Borland 
development tools such as Delphi or Kylix.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Ссылку на эту цитату можно?

Comment: Пожалуйста: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/cbuilder6/EN/CB6_ObjPascalLangGuide_EN.pdf  15я страница. Где-то на работе у меня есть твёрдая копия этого мануала, пришедшая  в боксе вместе с Delphi :)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Документ со ссылкой на сайт borland.com меня, мягко говоря, не убеждает. Борланда нет уже много лет

Comment: Но именно он создал Delphi, развивая Object Pascal. Да, Embarcadero, похоже, принципиально сделало ребрэндинг, фактически заменяя все упоминания Object Pascal на Delphi. Подозреваю, сделано это из маркетинговых и патентных соображений.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, есть две позиции: от Borland (которая, хоть и почила в бозе(точно?), но всё же является автором этого весьма удачного проекта), которая считала Delphi надстройкой, IDE (возможны варианты, не буду углубляться), и Embarcadero, которая купила проект и сейчас интенсивно отрабатывает вложения (знаю не понаслышке) и которой с маркетинговой ТЗ выгодной называть вещи так или иначе.
По большому счёту, нам должно быть всё равно. Остаётся вопрос - "что сделать с меткой". Предлагаю её разделить, если это возможно. Вряд ли стоит как-то пытаться переформировать старые вопросы, пусть они останутся. Что касается новых - а, что, так много **молодых** людей знает, что такое Object Pascal? А  вот про Delphi знают многие, так что перебора в использовании, на мой неискушенный взгляд, не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Понимать Delphi просто как IDE не совсем корректно, потому что в таком случае у конкретного языка программирования не остается названия. Называть этот язык просто Object Pascal нельзя, потому что Object Pascal - это общее название для нескольких близких языков программирования. К тому же начиная с Delphi 7 язык программирования официально назвали Delphi.

Получается, что для вопросов именно по языку программирования метка delphi подходит лучше чем object-pascal. Что же до вопросов которые и правда не имеют отношения к delphi - то им нужны другие метки.

Получается, что лучше оставить object-pascal синонимом. Если вопрос относится к delphi - то при вводе object-pascal получится правильная метка. Если вопрос к delphi не относится - то автор вопроса это увидит и поставит другую метку.

Comment: Пожалуй, не соглашусь. Скорее можно определить Delphi как надстройку над Object Pascal, выполненной в виде компонентов, написанных на языке Object Pascal, и инструментов разработчика, которые созданы из тех же компонентов.

Answer (score -2):

### А давайте снесём метку [object-pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-pascal) *совсем*.

То есть, вы утверждаете, что Object Pascal'ей на самом деле **несколько** и это не один язык, а целое **семейство языков**, в которое Delphi* всего лишь **входит**.

И это определённо правда. Из [соседнего ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6645/181100):

> Первоначально носил название Object Pascal и *исторически восходит к одноимённому диалекту языка, разработанному в фирме Apple в 1986 году* группой Ларри Теслера.

Вот контрпример того, что Object Pascal уместен в роли синонима Delphi. Но это ещё не всё.

Вот определение Object Pascal [из вики Free Pascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Object_Pascal):

> Object Pascal это собирательный термин для диалектов Pascal, в которых есть особенности для поддержки объектно-ориентированного программирования (ООП). Первыми версиями Pascal с поддержкой ООП были Clascal и Macintosh Pascal. Более современные реализации расширяют классовую модель, как Delphi и Free Pascal.

Я считаю уже это достаточным, чтобы *отменить синонимизацию*. Окей. Я за.

Если отменить синонимизацию, нужна ли будет вообще метка [object-pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-pascal)? Какую сколько-нибудь самостоятельную область вопросов она будет описывать? Я думаю, что её просто нет. Что во всех случаях больше смысла употребить более конкретную метку, касающуюся конкретной реализации Object Pascal. [inno-setup](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup), [free-pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-pascal), [delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) или что-то другое. Если у вас есть примеры вопросов, в которых так поступать не стоит, прошу сообщить мне в комментариях, будем думать.

Или, альтернативно, можно оставить эту метку, но отметить в её описании, что вместо неё наверняка будут уместнее более конкретные метки. Что-то вроде:

> Object Pascal является целым семейством языков с большим разнообразием особенностей. Используйте метку, касающуюся той реализации, которую используете вы: [delphi], [free-pascal], [inno-setup] и т. д. Не используйте эту метку если ваш вопрос не касается всего семейства.

---

*  Да, [Delphi это таки и язык](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Delphi_Language_Reference), а не только [IDE](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).

Comment: Вы передергиваете. "несколько и это не один язык, а целое семейство языков" - где это утверждалось?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov в вопросе. Вы приводите несколько примеров того, где используется Object Pascal, но не Delphi. Но ни один из этих языков реально Object Pascal'ем не называется.

Comment: @D-side  В вики сказано, что Inno Setup использует Object Pascal.

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov а на сайте Inno Setup нет.

Comment: @D-side (Пастернака не читал, но осуждаю :D) Сейчас схожу почитаю. Но не кажется ли, что это тот самый повод, когда стоит определится, на что ссылаться. Мне как научнику тоже смешно, как и ТС, когда ссылаются на вики

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov если размещённая проверяемая информация позволяет сделать определённые выводы, то совершенно неважно, где она размещена. На вики FP именно такая. И на вики-проектах в целом на непроверенных участках положено оставлять метку `[цитата?]`/`[citation needed]`. Для цитаты из FP источник указан, собственно, в ней самой. Интересующиеся могут пробить историю отдельных упомянутых языков самостоятельно.